# Hiding first-child of parent using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table with rows, and I am trying to hide all children EXCEPT the first-child until you click on a button. This is my code so far:

```
console.log(shipmentNumbers);
        for (let i = 0; i < shipmentNumbers.length; i += 1) {
            let sNumber = shipmentNumbers[i];
            console.log($('#status' + sNumber))
            $('#status' + sNumber).on('click', getHistory);


            var flagMore = false;
            $("#shipmentTable:not(:first-child)").hide();
            $("#more-button" + sNumber).on('click', function () {
                $('#shipment' + sNumber + ' tr.showmore').show();
                $(this).hide();
                $("#fewer-button" + sNumber).show();
                flagMore = true;
            });

            $("#fewer-button" + sNumber).on('click', function () {
                $('#shipment' + sNumber + ' tr.showmore').hide();
                $(this).hide();
                $("#more-button" + sNumber).show();
                flagMore = false;
            });
        }
```

What I expect is that $("#shipmentTable:not(:first-child)") would only show the first-child of the shipment table, and hide the rest. However, this is hiding everything so that no table rows appear. What am I doing wrong?

This is my html:

```
var shipmentBodyItems = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < shipment.itemDetails.length; i += 1) {
                shipmentBodyItems += `<tr id="shipmentTable">
                    <td class="item-name"> ` + shipment.itemDetails[i].title + `</td>
                    <td class="item-qty"> ` + shipment.itemDetails[i].qty + `</td>
                </tr>`;
            }
```

Comment: try this :- `$("#shipmentTable tr :not(:first)").hide();`. Please provide a working fiddle link of your problem so that you will get correct answer quickly.

Comment: __Identifiers__ in HTML must be __unique__ Generated HTML is invalid due to duplicate use of id `shipmentTable`, use class selector instead

Comment: @AlivetoDie `shipmentTable` is id to `<tr>`, hence your code snippet will not work

Comment: @Satpal yes you are right. sorry i din'r see that. KatherineMichelle  make sure that `id` will unique for every element (`tr's`) . So use `class` instead of `id`

Answer (score 0):

try this:--

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
   $("#myTbl tr:first-child").hide();
    });
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTbl" style="width:100%">

  
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button name="btn" id="btnSubmit" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:gt(index)` selector...check document [here](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

you can write like this in Jquery

```
$(".table > tr:gt(0)").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#shipmentTable:not(:first-child)")` wasn't a bad idea.
The only problem with that, it's that `id` needs to be unique!

Changing it to `$(".shipmentTable:not(:first-child)")` makes it work.

See snippet for example:

```js
// Added to have some data
var shipment = {
  itemDetails: [{
      title: "title 1",
      qty: "1"
    },
    {
      title: "title 2",
      qty: "2"
    },
    {
      title: "title 3",
      qty: "3"
    }
  ]
}

var shipmentBodyItems = '';
for (let i = 0; i < shipment.itemDetails.length; i += 1) {
  // Here, I changed tr "id" to "class" !
  shipmentBodyItems += `<tr class="shipmentTable">
                    <td class="item-name"> ` + shipment.itemDetails[i].title + `</td>
                    <td class="item-qty"> ` + shipment.itemDetails[i].qty + `</td>
                </tr>`;
}
$('table tbody').html(shipmentBodyItems); // Added to have something visual

// Your code wasn't bad, the only mistake was using id instead of class
// (id needs to be unique!)
$(".shipmentTable:not(:first-child)").hide();
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table id="#shipmentTable">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

I know that's an old topic, but anyway…

Hope it helps!